# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '' while converting string into int value

Tags: python, sockets, serversocket, tclientsocket

I am try to send/recv data over socket. I am getting this error while convert string to an integer value. this integer value is the length of filename.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\Nitesh Rathi\Desktop\clientSocket.py", line 16, in <module>

buff = int(filesize)

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Code

sending side

```
from socket import *
import os


HOST = '192.168.1.7'
PORT = 9999
ADDRESS = (HOST, PORT)

soc = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
soc.bind(ADDRESS)
soc.listen(5)
print('listen for connection...')
conn, addr = soc.accept()
print('got connection from', addr)

filename = 'file1.txt'.encode('utf-8')
fl = len(filename)
fl = str(fl)
print('size of filename :', fl, 'bytes')

conn.send(fl.encode('utf-8'))
print('size of filename sent')
conn.send(filename)
print('filename sent')
filedata = 'this is file1 data'.encode('utf-8')
conn.sendall(filedata)
print('data sent')


conn.close()
soc.close()
print('socket closed')
```

receiving side

```
from socket import *
import os


HOST = '192.168.1.7'
PORT = 9999
ADDRESS = (HOST, PORT)
PATH = "C:/Users/Nitesh Rathi/Desktop/RECV"

soc = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
soc.connect(ADDRESS)
print('connected to', ADDRESS)

while True:
    filesize = soc.recv(255).decode('utf-8')
    buff = int(filesize)
    print("size of filename: ", filesize, 'bytes')
    filename = soc.recv(buff).decode('utf-8')
    if not filename: break
    Path = os.path.join(PATH, filename)
    print(Path)
    file = open(Path, 'wb')
    filedata = soc.recv(1024)
    file.write(filedata)
    file.close()


soc.close()
print('socket closed')
print('data recvd')
```

Comment: You need to provide a complete, minimal, working example of your code. For example, you are missing import statements at the very least. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I'm not sure why this is failing - but assuming that you're using TCP sockets, the whole approach is broken anyway.  If the sender sends both the length and the filename without waiting for a response in between, then the receiver may receive *any* prefix of that data in a single call: it might be the whole thing, it might be the length and a part of the filename, or it might not even be the whole length.  There is *absolutely no connection* between what is sent with a single `.send()`, and what is received with a single `.recv()`.

Comment: @probat I will edit it and add complete server/client code now.

Comment: @jasonharper Than sir what is the correct way to send and receive files using tcp socekt? and yes my sender send both filename and filename length.

Comment: as @jasonharper said - receiver may get all data (filesize and file content) as one string. `filesize` converted to string may use different number of bytes and client cant recognize where is end of string with filesize and beginning of data. One method is to send new line after string with size and client has to read single bytes till it get new line - and then convert it to number - this method uses HTTP to get header. OR you can use `struct()` to convert to structure which will have always 4 bytes and client always will have to receive 4 bytes to get filesize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TCP stream sockets implement a stream protocol, not a message protocol and the received must therefore know in advance how many bytes it should receive.

Your code is sending the filename length as a string, followed by the length and this is an ambiguous protocol... for example if the filename is `42beers.txt` your code will write to the stream

```
0x31  '1'
0x31  '1'
0x34  '4'
0x32  '2'
0x62  'b'
0x65  'e'
0x65  'e'
0x72  'r'
0x73  's'
0x2e  '.'
0x74  't'
0x78  'x'
0x74  't'
```

How can the reader know when the length is finished and when the filename starts?

Note that the first `recv` call may in theory get just `1` or it could get `1142b` (because it's a byte stream channel, not a message channel).

**The error you are getting is probably because of this second possibility.**

For example an alternative approach that could work if your filenames are never bigger than 255 bytes in length is to write a single byte to represent the length of the string, followed by the string... i.e.

```
0x0B  11 (length of filename)
0x34  '4'
0x32  '2'
0x62  'b'
0x65  'e'
0x65  'e'
0x72  'r'
0x73  's'
0x2e  '.'
0x74  't'
0x78  'x'
0x74  't'
```

This way the receiver can use `read(1)` to get one byte (the length) and then do another `read(sz)` to get the filename.

To recap `recv` gives you whatever was received so far from the network and it can be less than what the sender passed with `send` or it can be a part of the join of multiple `send` calls from the writer. If you use `recv` then you must do a loop that keeps accumulating until the data has been received (and you must know how much that is or you must use separators like e.g. CRLF as http does in the request header).